# LXC: How do I mount a folder from the host to the container?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, lxc

I'm trying to mount a folder on the host to an LXC container.

The host has a folder `/mnt/ssd/solr_data` created (this is currently on the root filesystem, but later I'll mount an SSD drive there, so I'm prepping for that).

I want that folder to mount as `/data` in the container.

So in the containers fstab file I have the following:

```
/mnt/ssd/solr_data      /var/lib/lxc/Solr4StandAlone/rootfs/data        ext4    defaults,noatime        0       0
```

But that's a no-go, I get this error starting the container:

```
lxc-start: No such file or directory - failed to mount '/mnt/ssd/solr_data' on '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lxc//data'
lxc-start: failed to setup the mounts for 'Solr4StandAlone'
lxc-start: failed to setup the container
lxc-start: invalid sequence number 1. expected 2
lxc-start: failed to spawn 'Solr4StandAlone'
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To create the directory automatically in the container, you can also add the `create=dir` option in the fstab :

```
/mnt/ssd/solr_data      /var/lib/lxc/Solr4StandAlone/rootfs/data        none   bind,create=dir
```

Edit : this is specific to LXC. See [this thread](https://lists.linuxcontainers.org/pipermail/lxc-devel/2013-December/006444.html)

> Just like we already had "optional", this adds two new LXC-specific mount flags:
>
> - create=dir (will do a mkdir_p on the path)
> - create=file (will do a mkdir_p on the dirname + a fopen on the path)
>
> This was motivated by some of the needed bind-mounts for the unprivileged containers.

Comment: What version of `mount` does this apply to? I couldn't find the option described in `mount(8)` on Ubuntu 14.04, for example.

Comment: Also not in the [latest `mount(8)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html)

Comment: indeed... looks like it works with lxc only. See [this thread on lxc-devel ML](https://lists.linuxcontainers.org/pipermail/lxc-devel/2013-December/006444.html)

Answer (score 18):

In `/var/lib/lxc/Solr4StandAlone/config` add a line reading:

```
lxc.mount.entry = /mnt/ssd/solr_data  /var/lib/lxc/Solr4StandAlone/rootfs/data none bind 0 0
```

Then `lxc-stop` stop your container and `lxc-start` your container again.

That is all that is needed.

ref: [reference link](https://wiki.debian.org/LXC#External_mounts_inside_the_container)

Comment: Your solution should get better review as it works with unprivileged LXC containers tool. The other ones won't work in this case. And probably selinux/apport would need to be tweaked to allow their method. +1 for your solution!

Answer (score 14):

As of 2015/09/30 a change resulting from a security patch breaks mounting to an absolute path with lxc.mount.entry in the config file.

Instead you can use a relative path

```
 lxc.mount.entry = /mnt/ssd/solr_data data none bind 0 0
```

See: https://wiki.debian.org/LXC#Bind_mounts_inside_the_container

Comment: Great addition, it works as an answer, it'll get upvoted so people see it soon. Thanks for adding to it!

Answer (score 11):

I had to create the `/data` folder in the local container before the mount would work properly.

I also used this fstab entry:

```
/mnt/ssd/solr_data      /var/lib/lxc/Solr4StandAlone/rootfs/data        none   bind     0       0
```

Comment: `bind` mount option is something that was missing in the OP. I believe it is the most important correction (present also in all the other working answers).

Answer (score 8):

As LXC has changed over time this can be very simple, but it stumped me for a bit, so wanted to contribute.  I also created a gist for this so i can remember myself, but simply using lxc config device will do the trick.

```
sudo lxc config device add Solr4StandAlone sdb disk source=/var/lib/lxc/Solr4StandAlone/rootfs/data path=mnt/ssd/solr_data
```

**Note** It is important to leave the front slash off the path argument due to a change mentioned by @biscuitNinja

[Mounting directories from container to host](https://gist.github.com/jeffdyke/d48dbaea067ee9bb3d947a132e55073e)

Comment: The ubuntu manpage has a nice example: `lxc config device add [<remote>:]container1 <device-name> disk source=/share/c1 path=opt`, where `source` is on the host machine and `path` lies within the container.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `libvirt` to create your `lxc` container, you can make the directory on the host to be `passthrough` as shown here:

```
root@localhost:/# cat /etc/libvirt/lxc/my_container.xml
...
 <filesystem type='mount' accessmode='passthrough'>
    <source dir='<dir on host>'/>
    <target dir='<dir on container>'/>
 </filesystem>
....
```