# Mount host folder to guest with LXC 2.x, but do it readonly?

Tags: lxc, lxd

**NB:** This question relates directly to [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/69072/5462) and in particular to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/304256/5462), but it's not a duplicate.

I'd like to share a folder from the host with the guest, but make sure that the guest's root cannot accidentally write to that folder.

The folder in my case is `/toolchains`, both on the host and the guest. And it contains a number of GCC-based toolchains used for targeting different platforms.

Now the sharing itself is trivial:

```
lxc config device add CONTAINER toolchains disk source=/toolchains path=toolchains
```

Technically it seems to be a bind-mount. However, inside the container a remount to make it readonly fails:

```
# mount -o remount,ro /toolchains
mount: cannot mount /dev/sda1 read-only
```

Unfortunately this doesn't provide a great level of detail.

For good measure I also tried this alternative:

```
# mount -o remount,ro,bind /toolchains
mount: cannot mount /dev/sda1 read-only
```

which was mentioned in `mount(8)` under `mount --bind,ro foo foo` ...

What options do I have to achieve what I want? I.e. share the host folder as readonly with the guest. Should I use some kind of union FS here or is my only true chance of getting a readonly mount to 1.) use a CIFS share or 2.) use some hook to bind-mount the host folder via the `mount` command from the host into the guest root?

I'm using LXC 2.20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens if you bind-mount your directory read-only on the host and then share it with the LXC container?

```
mount --bind /toolchains /toolchains-ro
mount -o remount,ro,bind /toolchains-ro
lxc config device add CONTAINER toolchains disk source=/toolchains-ro path=toolchains
```

Technically everything what is read-only on the host level should remain read-only in the container.

Comment: Confirmed, I just tried that method, albeit in the hosts /etc/fstab instead of on the command line, and it works like a charm. The guest shows the mount as readonly now. Attempts to remove anything fail with the error: `Read-only file system`.

Comment: Now in 2020, this can be done without the bind mounts as `lxc config device add CONTAINER toolchains disk source=/toolchains path=toolchains readonly=true`